# Python not getting arguments passed to it from shell script

Tags: python, command-line, argv

I have a shell script that calls various python scripts and passes an argument it got onto the python scripts. However, the python scripts are currently not getting the argument. when i go to sys.argv it instead shows something completely different. I have the code and sys.argv below:

Shell Script (called run_everything.sh) :

```
#!/bin/bash

source venv/bin/activate

python3 eval_otare_on_otare.py $1
```

then i have a line in `eval_otare_on_otare.pt` that prints the arguments passed:
 `print(sys.argv)`

And I get the following list:

> ['eval_care_on_otare.py', 'run_everything.sh']

what can I do because sys.argv is clearly not getting what I want, I want it to return

> ['eval_care_on_otare.py', $1]

where $1 is the argument passed

Comment: Are you sure you used `$1` and not `$0` in the bash script?

Comment: Perhaps add some echo's or other prints in your bash script to confirm that $1 is the parameter you want.

Comment: Your script is clearlyea [tag:bash] script; thus I removed the [tag:sh] tag. See also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Answer (score 0):

If your `activate` script messes up the value of `$1`, save it first.

```
#!/bin/bash

arg=$1

source ./venv/bin/activate

python3 eval_otare_on_otare.py "$arg"
```

Tangentially note also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)